# AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'post'. is it deprecated and new function has been introduced?

Tags: python, rest, flask, python-requests, localhost

I've been trying to send requests to a local server built using flask.
requests are sent using `requests` module of python.

I don't know if that `requests.post` function has been deprecated and new one's introduced or is there anything really wrong with my code. I've done everything exactly as said in [this article](https://hackernoon.com/deploy-a-machine-learning-model-using-flask-da580f84e60c).
Here's my code:

```
import requests

host_url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000"

# get the data
data_for_prediction = [int(input()) for _ in range(10)]
r = requests.post(url=host_url,json={data_for_prediction})
print(r.json())
```

The error I'm getting for above code is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/--/requests.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\--\requests.py", line 8, in <module>
    r = requests.post(url=host_url,json={data_for_prediction})
AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'post'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

my server code is:

```
flask_server_app = Flask(__name__)

# let's make the server now
@flask_server_app.route("/api/predict", methods=["GET", "POST"])
# my prediction function goes here
def predict():
    # Get the data from the POST request & reads the received json
    json_data = request.get_json(force=True)

    # making prediction
    # Make prediction using model loaded from disk as per the data.
    prediction = ml_model.predict([[json_data]])

    # return json version of the prediction
    return jsonify(prediction[0])

# run the app now
if __name__ == '__main__':
    flask_server_app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

I've tried checking documentation, checked many articles online and also re-wrote the whole code. But, none helped.

So, is that `requests.post` function deprecated and a new one's been introduced or is there anything wrong with my code.

Comment: (Please do not vandalise a question after it is answered - we are keen to preserve questions as they were asked, as per the licensing conditions in the footer).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like you are writing your code in a file called `requests.py` so when you try to import the requests module, it does import your own file as a module. Try renaming your file...

Comment: that was really stupid of me to not check the name. thank you.